# How to verify human identity while using Lynx browser

Tags: lynx

I am going to test a website which uses a firewall for security.

I will test this website using Lynx browser (its a text based browser) so I am unable to verfiy my identity when a human verification is prompted for DDOS check.

Please suggest, how to access this site.